# How to do text search in mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm trying to search "efg" in field named "abc"

```
c.Find(bson.M{"$text": bson.M{"abc": "efg"}})
```

c is Collection object. I'm not getting any result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to do text search in mongodb shell?

Comment: yeah, even in mongo shell, I'm not getting expected result.

Comment: Have you prepare your database correctly, I'm not do text search yet but I think you must enable something or build some kind of index...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are generating `{$text:{abc:"efg"}}`, but your query should look like this:
`{$text:{$search:"efg"}}`

So try updating your code to:

```
c.EnsureIndexKey("abc")
c.Find(bson.M{"$text": bson.M{"$search": "efg"}})
```

Keep in mind that to search with `$text`, you need to specify an index. Check out this document that explains how to use it: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/

Answer (score 2):

use $regex(option i for case insensitive)
example:

```
c.Find(bson.M{"abc": &bson.RegEx{Pattern: "efg", Options: "i"}})
```

Comment: I think he's asking specifically about search with MongoDB Text Indexes.